# Excel : Getting first values out of a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(First of all, sorry that the pictures are linked and not displayed, but I still don't have 10 reputation to do so :'( )

Hello everyone !

I'm in need of your advices and answers : Despite searching through the Internet, I couldn't find anything for my problem. So, I'm coming here, in hope that you all can enlight me.

I'm having a data table looking something like this : (This is an example)

[image: Example 1]

For copy / paste:

```
Name Index Val 1  Val 2 Val 3
AAA  1     121    12    81921
BBB  2     651    9491  1
CCC  3     11     90121 210
DDD  4     612    18    29
EEE  5     1441   12    123
FFF  6     12     1921  51
GGG  7     210    120   1245
…    …     …       …    …
```

I'm looking for formulas that will allow me to get the 5 highest values of a specific type, then display it in the following formant : (Another example handmade)

[image: Example 2]

Which will look like this :

```
Name    Val 1               Name    Val 2               Name    Val 3
EEE     1441                CCC     90121               AAA     81921
BBB     651                 BBB     9491                GGG     1245
DDD     612                 FFF     1921                CCC     210
GGG     210                 GGG     120                 EEE     123
AAA     121                 DDD     18                  FFF     51
```

In each different newly-created table, I should have the 5 highest datas of a given value.
Ideally, these new tables should be automatically updated when new datas are entered in the main table, so that there is no need to recheck everything.

Thanks a lot for your future answers ! If you need answers to better understand my problem and what I'd need, I'll love to answer you !

Comment: You should post your data as text instead of images.

Comment: Thanks, edition done :3

Comment: How are 1441, 90121 and 81921 not the *'5 highest datas of a given value'*

Comment: Only because I failed my example >< Edited by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating appropriate column header labels, put these two formulas in G2:H2.

```
=INDEX($A:$A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($B$2:INDEX($B:$B, MATCH(1E+99, $B:$B)))/(INDEX($A:$E, 2, MATCH(H$1, $A$1:$E$1, 0)):INDEX($A:$E, MATCH(1E+99, $B:$B),  MATCH(H$1, $A$1:$E$1, 0))=H2), COUNTIF(H$2:H2, H2)))
=AGGREGATE(14, 7, INDEX($A:$E, 2, MATCH(H$1, $A$1:$E$1, 0)):INDEX($A:$E, MATCH(1E+99, $B:$B), MATCH(H$1, $A$1:$E$1, 0)), ROW(1:1))
```

Fill down four additional rows then copy G2:H6 to J2:K6 and M2:N6.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! <3